# Custom distribution option in setup.py

Tags: python, distutils

How to pass custom key-value pairs in `setup()` parameters? I need them for a custom `build_scripts` step.

```
from distutils.core import setup

from somescripts import build_scripts

setup(name='somescripts',
      version=__version__,
      cmdclass= {
                 'build_scripts': build_scripts,
                 },
      custom_pairs={
          'compile_modules': True,
          'use_scons': True,
          'modules': [f for f in glob('scripts/[!_]*.spy')],
      },
)
```

This gives "UserWarning: Unknown distribution option" in `setup.py install` (which turns into error with `--strict`)

```
c:\python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution
 option: 'custom_pairs'
warnings.warn(msg)
```

**UPDATE**:

- distutils doesn't call `build_scripts` at all if `scripts` kwarg is empty

Comment: IIRC you should use them directly as parameters in `setup()` call, not packed into a dict.

Comment: @Lav they will still all be `Unknown distribution option`

Comment: Hmm, actually where did you find these options? I don't have a lot of experience with distutils, but I've checked reference for distutils and setuptools, as well as their source codes, and can't find these options anywhere.

Comment: @Lav the question is about the need I had to pass the params, and it is not necessary that distutils supported that at the moment. Probably it still does not, so it is about hacking distutils to get the thing done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way myself.

```
from distutils.command.build_scripts import build_scripts as base
from distutils.core import setup

# patch distutils so that it won't skip "build_scripts"
# step if `scripts` list is empty
from distutils.dist import Distribution
def custom_has_scripts(self):
    return True
Distribution.has_scripts = custom_has_scripts

class build_scripts(base):
    def initialize_options(self):
        self.compile_modules = None
        self.use_scons = None
        self.modules = None
    def run(self):
        for module in self.modules:
            # generate scripts
            pass

setup(name='somescripts',
      version=__version__,
      cmdclass= {
                 'build_scripts': build_scripts,
                 },
      options={
          'build_scripts':{
              'compile_modules': True,
              'use_scons': True,
              'modules': [f for f in glob('scripts/[!_]*.spy')],
          },
      },
)
```